# IIRF How to redirect CRUD requests

Tags: proxy, reverse-proxy, iirf

I'm trying to make IIRF redirect POST UPDATE DELETE  requests, not only GET one.
Here is the config

```
RedirectRule ^/web1$ /web2/ [I]
ProxyPass ^/web1/(.*)$ http://another.example.com:25000/web2/$1
ProxyPassReverse /web1 http://another.example.com:25000/web2/
```

How do I do this functionality?
Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

IIRF works for all verbs.

You don't need to do anything else.

Answer (score 0):

Try to check this manual: https://web.archive.org/web/20140421191230/http://dotnetzip.herobo.com/Iirf21Help/frames.htm

Check the final part:

> Optional: If you want to use ProxyPass with POST, you must also configure the DLL as a ISAPI Extension. To do this, within IIS Manager, on the left hand side, right click the Web Sites node, and select Properties.

I don't know how to do it in II6.1, but this could help you.